# Can a function detect whether it has been piped into?

Tags: r, magrittr

Is there a way for a function to detect whether a magrittr pipe has passed data into it?

#### A motivating example:

Certain functions like `ifelse()` don't work well with magrittr input.

```
1:4 %>% ifelse(. < 3, "low", "high")
#> Error in ifelse(., . < 3, "low", "high") : unused argument ("high")
```

results in an error.

To make the function work as intended, you have to use

```
1:4 %>% {ifelse(. < 3, "low", "high")}
#> "low"  "low"  "high" "high"
```

Is there a way to redefine a function so that it behaves differently when piped into?

#### My best attempt:

```
my_ifelse <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)

  if (sys.call()[[2]] == ".") args <- args[-1]

  ifelse(test = args[[1]], yes = args[[2]], no = args[[3]])
}

1:4 %>% my_ifelse(. < 3, "low", "high")
#> "low"  "low"  "high" "high"
```

Are there any issues with this solution? Could it break unexpectedly?

Edit: Obviously, this will return an error if an incorrect number of arguments are passed. A more full-fledged approach would attempt to provide informative errors and even potentially allow use argument names rather than `...`

Comment: Untested but I think `my_ifelse <- function(x, ...) ifelse(...)` should work. I believe yours doesn't work if no is missing.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper This is an excellent and simple solution! The one downside is that it can't replicate the usual ifelse() functionality when it isn't piped. But if you know the function will always be piped, this is much better than my pass at it!

Comment: You can also define your own pipe that does not insert implicit dots: `"%>>%" <- function(lhs, rhs) eval(substitute(rhs), envir = list(. = lhs), enclos = parent.frame())`

Answer (score 2):

When we use pipe we know that the left-hand side of pipe is treated as the first argument to the function on the right-hand side.

So you can't expect this to work :

```
1:4 %>% ifelse(. < 3, "low", "high")
```

Since what this actually means is

```
ifelse(1:4, 1:4 < 3, "low", "high")
```

which gives you the exact same error

> Error in ifelse(1:4, 1:4 < 3, "low", "high") : unused argument ("high")

Yes, you can stop this default behavior by using `{}` around pipes.

I am not sure what your final goal is but a general rule which can be followed is all the changes that you want to do on the input should be done on LHS side only unless you want to use `{}`.

So this works :

```
(1:4 < 3) %>% ifelse("low", "high")
#[1] "low"  "low"  "high" "high"
```

Comment: Another example that might help OP understand: `sum(x > 2)` is a standard way to find out how many elements of `x` are greater than 2, and `sum(1:4 > 2)` correctly gives 2. Of course `1:4 %>% sum(. > 2)` doesn't get the right answer, we get 12 because it becomes `sum(1:4, 1:4 > 2)`, which is `sum(10, 2)`, which is `12`. But this doesn't have anything to do with the way the function is written - it has everything to do with the fact that the `1:4 %>% sum(. > 2)` is an attempt to pipe in part of an argument instead of the whole thing.

Comment: This is intended behavior from `magrittr`, and [is called out in the readme](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr): *"It is straightforward to use the placeholder `.` several times in a right-hand side expression. However, when the placeholder only appears in a nested expressions `magrittr` will still apply the first-argument rule. The reason is that in most cases this results more clean code."*, with examples that follow. So the pipe could be rewritten to work as OP desires, with no changes to the function that is piped into.